# How to scale down the values in my 2d numpy array without losing information

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix, data-science

I have a square 2d array of of size n, filled with numeric values.

For each entry, I sum that entry's row and column, but subtract the original entry away.

```
while 1:
    new = np.copy(next)
    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(n):
            val = new[i][j] 
            rowsum = np.sum(new[i])
            colsum = np.sum(new[:,j])
            next[i][j] = rowsum+colsum-val-val
```

Accomplishes what I want, but after some iterations, entries often get too large (since they are nearly doubling).  I would like to periodically scale down my values, but I want to do so such that I don't lose information.  The important information is the percentage difference between any two entries.

I want to avoid scaling in a way that makes entries negative.

The range of input is not limited in any way.  It would be especially great if I could scale it in some way so that negative entries would become positive.

I thought that normalizing the matrix might work, but it ended up pushing values together and after some amount of loops all of the values were pretty much equal.

Comment: what are you trying to do, exactly?  This code is not optimal, but your question is quite complicated.  I suggest you try to clarify what you're doing or break it into a few smaller questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could after summing apply a function that is bounded like a sigmoid function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

[image]

So if you take the sum of the rows and columns for a value, then plug that value into the sigmoid function this will prevent the number from ever going outside of the range (0,1). This way you wont get the numbers exploding, no matter how many times you perform this operation.

There might be other functions that may work better for what you have in mind but the idea is the same. Use a function that has a bounded range and if your outputs are the outputs of this function, then the numbers you are using will always have the same bounds.

This (or something like this) is what is used in nodes of a neural network. Since the output of the node is the sum of all connected nodes earlier in the network you can get the same effect where the numbers blow up. Sometimes in NNs they call this a squishing function, or squashing.

Answer (score 2):

"I thought that normalizing the matrix might work, but it ended up pushing values together and **after some amount of loops all of the values were pretty much equal.**"

This is actually expected and is not an effect of normalization.

To understand why first observe that your operation is actually circular convolution with the kernel that is zero everywhere except the first row and first column but also zero in the top left corner and has nonzero values all equal.

We can check this in numpy

```
>>> from scipy.fftpack import fftn, ifftn
>>> 
>>> def iterate(new):
...     next = new.copy()
...     for i in xrange(n):
...         for j in xrange(n):
...             val = new[i][j] 
...             rowsum = np.sum(new[i])
...             colsum = np.sum(new[:,j])
...             next[i][j] = rowsum+colsum-val-val
...     return next
... 
>>> n = 8
>>> kernel = np.arange(n)==0
>>> kernel = np.bitwise_xor.outer(kernel, kernel)
>>> 
>>> data = np.random.random((n, n))
>>> 
>>> np.allclose(ifftn(fftn(data) * fftn(kernel)).real, iterate(data))
True
```

Multiple iterations are the same as taking powers of the kernel in the Fourier domain:

```
>>> np.allclose(ifftn(fftn(data) * fftn(kernel)**3).real, iterate(iterate(iterate(data))))
True
```

So let's have a look at the kernel in Fourier space:

```
>>> fftn(kernel).real
array([[14.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.],
       [ 6., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2.],
       [ 6., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2.],
       [ 6., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2.],
       [ 6., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2.],
       [ 6., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2.],
       [ 6., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2.],
       [ 6., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2.]])
```

As we can see there is a dominant entry in the top left corner which is the constant mode i.e. a global offset when transformed back.
Obviously, if we take powers of this FT'ed kernel the constant mode will become more and more dominant. This will also apply to the product of the FT'ed data with this power, so the after back transform the relative differences between elements will become smaller and smaller.

You could try and remedy this by global mean subtraction. It is easy to verify that the powers of the FT'ed kernel will then converge to a scalar multiple of the original kernel:

```
>>> np.round((fftn(kernel-kernel.mean()).real)**100 / 10.**75, 20)
array([[  0.  , 653.32, 653.32, 653.32, 653.32, 653.32, 653.32, 653.32],
       [653.32,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
       [653.32,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
       [653.32,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
       [653.32,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
       [653.32,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
       [653.32,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ],
       [653.32,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ,   0.  ]])
```

As everything is real, the back FT of this is the same as the forward FT which we've seen already. So iterating with mean subtraction will converge up to scalar factor to the circular convolution with the FT of the original kernel.